# Be clear in the Stack Exchange Android app error message when a question is deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, android-app, error-message

When viewing my feed on the mobile application, I attempted to access a post I'd left a comment on. After following the link, I received an error stating "The post was unable to load."

At first I thought I was having connection issues on my device. However, after trying to load the question in a browser, it brought me to the post-removed page.

Perhaps it would be better to display some sort of indication that a post had been deleted inside of the mobile feed? On the other hand, the error displayed on the mobile application could be reworded to better represent the post's status.

Comment: @crabolo android

Comment: This also happens when you want to open a comment on a question/answer from the feed. The scenario is when the comment would be deleted, but the parent post would not be deleted.